How to smooth it out?
I corrected the model and instead of a smooth one, now this. How to smooth the model correctly? It is needed to export to the game. I tried Subdivision, but none of the settings helped.I've heard something about custom normals, but I don't understand anything about it. 

This looks like all your faces are separated from each other... how did you "correct" the model? Try selecting all in Edit Mode with A, then M > Merge > By Distance.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
